# how to solve A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'

Tags: flutter, gradle

A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
>
> > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

```
 android {
     namespace 'com.example.namespace'
 }
```

If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml,
 it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle 
file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to
 https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> I have followed the link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant
> Because of my Gradle 8.0.0, it doesn't show when the project operates in Android.
> I have installed firebase cli and it doesn't show up. But more importantly, this command is still error ./gradlew signingreport still not passed.

Comment: Hey @Ake did you get the solution for this specific issue, I am facing it after upgrading my Gradle version to 8.1.1

Comment: same issue as @Danc-0. Any help?